# Printing a void c++

Tags: c++, printing, void

To give background on my code. I'm supposed to take the user input, find the month and day they input in the txt file and print that out which sound sooo simple to me but I just can't get my code to work. I want to take that I created and put it in the main so I can print whatever I have cout in that void code. I wanted some guidance to see where exactly I'm going wrong.

````
int main() {

    cout << "please enter month first and then day: ";
    cin >> searchMonth;
    cin >> searchDay;
    if (searchMonth == month && searchDay == day){
        for (int i=0; i<TOTALDATA; i++){
            infile >> year >> month >> day >> hour >> minute >> latitude >> longitude >> magnitude >> state;
            earthquakeData oneEarthquake;
            oneEarthquake.yearOfEarthquake = year;
            oneEarthquake.monthOfEarthQuake = month;
            oneEarthquake.dayOfEarthquake = day;
            oneEarthquake.hourOfEarthquake = hour;
            oneEarthquake.minOfEarthquake = minute;
            oneEarthquake.yearOfEarthquake = latitude;
            oneEarthquake.earthquakeLatitude = longitude;
            oneEarthquake.earthquakeMagnitude = magnitude;
            oneEarthquake.earthquakeState = state;
            earthquakes[i] = oneEarthquake;// row i is set to oneEarthquake
            earthquakeDetails (earthquakes[i]) ;
        }
    }
    infile.close();
    return 0;
}
void earthquakeDetails (earthquakeData earthquakes[TOTALDATA]){
    for (int i=0; i<TOTALDATA; i++){
        cout << earthquakes[i].yearOfEarthquake;
        cout << earthquakes[i].monthOfEarthQuake;
        cout << earthquakes[i].dayOfEarthquake;
        cout << earthquakes[i].hourOfEarthquake << ":" << earthquakes[i].minOfEarthquake;
        cout << earthquakes[i].earthquakeLatitude << earthquakes[i].earthquakeLongitude;
        cout << earthquakes[i].earthquakeMagnitude;
        cout << earthquakes[i].earthquakeState;
    }
}```
````

Comment: Can you, please, emphasize where specifically you try to print a `void`? Couldn't you strip you code a bit to make a [mcve] (with focus on "minimal")?

Comment: Sorry not really sure how to post here just yet but I made it shorter. I'm trying to print earthquakeDetails. I have it in the for loop right now.

Comment: There are some confusing things in your program. 1.) What does the `if (searchMonth == month && searchDay == day)` intend to do? `month` and `day` are uninitialized where they are checked. 2.) The loop `for (int i=0; i<TOTALDATA; i++){` is inside the `if` body. Shouldn't it be vice versa? 3.) Shouldn't you first read a value for `day` and `month` and then compare them to `searchMonth` and `searchDay`? 4.) The `earthquakeDetails()` iterates over the whole array but it is called inside the `for` loop of `main()`. Thus, it will iterate over a partially initialized array most times.

Comment: To see, what happens, please, debug your program step-wise. This will uncover to you what it actually does. (And, I hardly believe it does what you expected it to do.)

Answer (score 0):

Things you are doing wrong:

- read from user without checking the input
- read from file before opening a file (or your MRE is incomplete)
- `if` outside of loop
- `if` before reading from file
- calling looping output function from looping search function